# Azure ElasticSearch Pricing & Maintenance

Tags: azure, elasticsearch

We were supposed to be on AWS ElasticSearch(ES) but now it is decided to go with Microsoft Azure.
I checked and found that offering is not of PaaS but take service from Market place.

I would like to know the cost of it. I saw below [thread](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/elastic-stack-pricing-on-azure/130915) and it is mentioned that cost will be same as it is in [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/pricing/) or GCP.

So in this case,

- Do we need to take care of Backup, maintenance or Azure will take care of it?
- High Availability (HA) will be handled during creation of ES environment ?
  What will be cost of HA

Answer (score 5):

So now we can host Elastic Search on Azure from 03-Sep-2019.

So we do not have to worry about maintenance, backups, great.

**Elasticsearch Service pricing**
https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch/service/pricing

**Price calculator**
https://cloud.elastic.co/pricing

Comment: Please advise on your experience with elastic cloud? Besides elastic cloud we also have self managed option in azure. We were also in middle of deciding which option to choose and hence wanted to check on your experience with the elastic cloud option.

Comment: Previously we were also using the self managed VMs to host ELK stack. But then upgrade,   backup/restore requires specific skillset and can't take much risk in production environment. So moving to cloud option gave us flexibility on scale up/down or scale out as well as by default 7 days (i think so, don't remember exact days) backup is part of plan we opt for. 
So i would suggest you to go for cloud option. We can monitor the usage and then based on trend we can decide to scale up/down accordingly. It comes up with CPU, Memory & disk size plans.
Hope this will help.